# Lever length in a spring balanced arm

Tags: geometry

[image: Click this link to see a diagram of the problem]

Given:
Length AB = L (known)
Length AC = r (known radius)
angle $\theta$ = known
angle BAD = 90
angle AEB = 90

Express length AE in terms of known (L, r, $\theta$)

I found that: angle ABC= angle EAD

Comment: What are your efforts

Comment: I found that: angle ABE = EAD. Tried to solve with basic trig and with law of sines, but couldn't see the solution.

Comment: The first step is to find BC by applying cosine law to triangle BAC.

Comment: Mick, thanks for the tip, I appreciate you were trying to coax me through the solution. I knew in myself the solution was simple, just had a mental block on it.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AE\quad =\sqrt { { r }^{ 2 }-{ CE }^{ 2 } } =\sqrt { { L }^{ 2 }-{ BE }^{ 2 } } \\ BE\quad =\quad BC+CE$

solving for $CE$...

$CE=\frac { L-{ r }^{ 2 }-{ BC }^{ 2 } }{ 2BC }$

law of cosines applied to triangle $ABC$

$BC\quad =\quad \sqrt { L+{ r }^{ 2 }-2Lrcos(90-\theta )}$

then  just plug n chug

$CE=\frac { L-{ r }^{ 2 }-L+{ r }^{ 2 }-2Lrcos(90-\theta ) }{ 2\sqrt { L+{ r }^{ 2 }-2Lrcos(90-\theta ) }  } =\frac { -Lrcos(90-\theta ) }{ \sqrt { L+{ r }^{ 2 }-2Lrcos(90-\theta ) }  } $

plug back into original equation for $AE$:

$AE=\sqrt { { r }^{ 2 }-{ \frac { -Lrcos(90-\theta ) }{ \sqrt { L+{ r }^{ 2 }-2Lrcos(90-\theta ) }  }  }^{ 2 } } $